# How to convert double to unsigned long long under rounding mode != FE_TOWARDZERO?

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion, double, unsigned-long-long-int

How to convert double to unsigned long long under rounding mode != `FE_TOWARDZERO`?

Extra: why there is no `ullrint` function?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What was the result?

Comment: @dbush Don't know how. The `(unsigned long long)double` always _truncates toward zero_ (C11, 6.3.1.4). There is no `ullrint`. Then how to do that?

Comment: Did you try `rint`?

Comment: @dbush Consider a case when the nearest integer value cannot be represented as `double`. Hence, `rint` will return the next representable integer value in floating-point format. So, we expect from `(ull)d` to return `X`, however, since `X` cannot be represented `rint` returns `Y`. How can you comment on that?

Comment: The nearest representable integer is necessarily representable as a `double`.  And assuming a `double` is represented as IEEE754 double-precision floating point, it has 53 bits of precision.  And assuming this value is in the range of an `unsigned long long`, it can be stored there.

Comment: Perhaps you could give a specific case you're concerted about, along with expected and actual results.

Comment: @dbush Example: from math point of view converting `...610.51` to integer under `FE_TONEAREST` leads to `...611.00`. However, `double` cannot represent `...610.51` and represents it as `...616.00`. Hence, `rint(d)` returns `...616.00`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with converting a `double` to `unsigned long long`, but is instead about the precision of a `double`.  A [mcve] would be helpful to see what you actually need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard C99 math functions `trunc()`, `ceil()`, `floor()`, and `rint()` (with an appropriately set rounding mode) can be used to first round the `double` value to the next integer value using the desired rounding mode, before converting to `unsigned long long` with a cast. Note that sufficiently large `double` values (those with magnitude >= 2<sup>53</sup>) are guaranteed to be integers, so there are no double-rounding issues in this approach.

Alternatively (e.g. when using a tool chain that only supports an older ISO-C standard that does not offer these standard math functions), one can easily perform the conversion with a little straightforward bit manipulation. The following example code demonstrates both approaches. It assumes that `uint64_t` and `unsigned long long` are identical under the hood, and that `double` maps to IEEE-754 `binary64`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fenv.h>
#include <math.h>

#define RN (1)
#define RZ (2)
#define RU (3)
#define RD (4)
#define TEST_RND_MODE (RD)

uint64_t double_as_uint64 (double a)
{
    uint64_t r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

uint64_t double_to_uint64 (double a, int rnd_mode)
{
    const uint64_t uint64_nan = 0x8000000000000000ULL;
    const uint64_t uint64_msb = 0x8000000000000000ULL;
    const int dbl_expo_bias = 1023;
    const int dbl_expo_bits = 11;
    const int dbl_expo_mask = ((1 << dbl_expo_bits) - 1);
    const int dbl_mant_bits = 52; // stored
    uint64_t t = 0ULL;
    uint64_t ai = double_as_uint64 (a);
    uint64_t r;
    int shift;

    /* special case handling: season to taste */
    if (isnan (a)) return uint64_nan;
    if (a >= 0x1.0p64) return 0ULL;
    if (a <= 0.0) return 0ULL;

    shift = (int)(dbl_expo_bias + 63 - ((ai >> dbl_mant_bits) & dbl_expo_mask));
    r = ((ai << dbl_expo_bits) | uint64_msb);
    if (shift >= 64) {
        t = r >> (shift > 64);
        r = 0;
    } else if (shift) {
        t = r << (64 - shift);
        r = r >> shift;
    }
    if ((rnd_mode == FE_TONEAREST) && (t >= uint64_msb)) {
        r += (t == uint64_msb) ? (r & 1) : 1;
    } else if ((rnd_mode == FE_UPWARD) && t) {
        r++;
    }
    return r;
}

double uint64_as_double (uint64_t a)
{
    double r;
    memcpy (&r, &a, sizeof r);
    return r;
}

static uint64_t kiss64_x = 1234567890987654321ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_c = 123456123456123456ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_y = 362436362436362436ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_z = 1066149217761810ULL;
static uint64_t kiss64_t;
#define MWC64  (kiss64_t = (kiss64_x << 58) + kiss64_c, \
                kiss64_c = (kiss64_x >> 6), kiss64_x += kiss64_t, \
                kiss64_c += (kiss64_x < kiss64_t), kiss64_x)
#define XSH64  (kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y << 13), kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y >> 17), \
                kiss64_y ^= (kiss64_y << 43))
#define CNG64  (kiss64_z = 6906969069ULL * kiss64_z + 1234567ULL)
#define KISS64 (MWC64 + XSH64 + CNG64)

int main (void)
{
    double x;
    uint64_t res, ref;

    do {
        x = fabs (uint64_as_double (KISS64));

#if TEST_RND_MODE == RZ
        res = double_to_uint64 (x, FE_TOWARDZERO);
        ref = (uint64_t)trunc(x);
#elif TEST_RND_MODE == RN
        res = double_to_uint64 (x, FE_TONEAREST);
        ref = (uint64_t)rint(x); // assumes current rounding mode is FE_TONEAREST!
#elif TEST_RND_MODE == RU 
        res = double_to_uint64 (x, FE_UPWARD);
        ref = (uint64_t)ceil(x);
#elif TEST_RND_MODE == RD
        res = double_to_uint64 (x, FE_DOWNWARD);
        ref = (uint64_t)floor(x);
#else
#error unsupported TEST_RND_MODE
#endif
        if (res != ref) {
            printf ("err @ % 22.13a: res=%016llx  ref=%016llx\n", x, res, ref);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    } while (1);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: FYI: the latest working draft (N2596) has funtions `fromfp, ufromfp` and `fromfpx, ufromfpx`, which have `unsigned int width` argument.